# Bullets not moving on screen

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Im in the process of making a simple gun to work with a sprite, I've done similar things like this but never using cocos2d. Heres what I have now but for some reason the bullets are not moving on screen, any help would be appreciated.

```
-(void)spinTapped
{
        [self.character stopAllActions];
        [self.character runAction:self.gunAction];
        isRunning = NO;
        CCSprite *bullet = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"rwby_bullet.png"];
        bullet.position = ccp(self.character.position.x , self.character.position.y);            
        [self addChild:bullet z:10];
        [bullets addObject:bullet];

}
```

Then in my update function:

```
if(isRight) bulletVelocity = 10;
    else if(isLeft) bulletVelocity = -10;

    for(CCSprite *bullet in bullets)
    {
        bullet.position = ccp(bullet.position.x + bulletVelocity, bullet.position.y);
    }
```

So the animation runs which means it is recognizing that the button is being pressed and the bullets appear but don't move. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: what happens if !isRight and !isLeft , ie is in limbo ? Put a breakpoint and check the value of bulletVelocity (inside the for loop). That will confirm for you that 'left right' state AND that bullets actually contains objects in your update method.

Comment: I had tried that, even just setting the bulletVelocity to 10 and getting rid of the isRight/isLeft but still no results, the bullet appears but stays frozen. It seems the for loop has something to do with it. I had added some values to respond to scrolling and even that did not do anything.

Comment: Oops I forgot to initialize the array, works fine now!